# How can I fit content with dynamic height to a page for print?

Tags: html, css

I do have two questions.

I'm expecting to print an HTML content to a 70mm width paper but height is dynamic and I'm expecting to print them using a POS printer (Jest as a POS bill print).

1. How to set 78mm x dynamic height paper size in @page css?
2. If I set paper width to 78mm and create a DIV with 78mm,at the print, div content is not printing all the 78mm width of the page. Means the 78mm printing div is smaller than the 78mm page. If I increase the div size up to about 95mm, then the result is pretty much decent. What is the reason for this? What is the correct way?

CSS code

```css
@page {
    size: 78mm 58mm;
}
```

in HTML

```html
<div style="max-width: 90mm; height:auto; color:black;font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; ">
```

Comment: Hard to tell without any code (can you post some?). I don't believe you can remove printer margins via CSS. Avoid "Fit to print" or similar options in your print preview.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I just added the code

Comment: Okay thanks! Mh not sure. Maybe use a proper print media query? Don't use `style` for a style you only want for print. Better not use `style` attributes at all. Use classes if you need them. Tutorial over here: [@media print, @page](https://www.jegsworks.com/lessons/web-2/html/step-mediaprint.htm)